# jQuery click function only called once

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I have some code that only fires the click event once. Can you guys take a look?

UPDATE:
I have edited the code to show the whole function. Im making a plugin for jQuery. Anyway, the point is that the code DOES WORK but the click function of `a.click()` ets fired only once, removing one filter only.

```
    addFilterProcess: function ()
    {
        var $this = this;
        var select_filters = this.select_filters;
        var selected_filter = select_filters.val();

        if (selected_filter != 0)
        {
            if (this.active_filters.length == 0)
            {
                this.active_filters.push(selected_filter);
                this.used_filters.append(this.template_show_filter(this.options.available_filters[selected_filter], selected_filter));


                var filter = this.used_filters.find('#filter-'+selected_filter);
                var a = filter.find('a');
                a.click(function () {
                    $this.removeFilter(a.attr('filter'));
                });

                this.btn_apply_filters.show();
                this.btn_cancel_filters.show();

                this.btn_apply_filters.on('click', function () {
                    $this.applyFilters();
                });
                this.btn_cancel_filters.on('click', function () {
                    $this.cancelFilters();
                });


                /*
                Reset the select, to show the first option
                 */
                select_filters.val(0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.active_filters.indexOf(selected_filter) === -1)
                {
                    this.active_filters.push(selected_filter);
                    this.used_filters.append(this.template_show_filter(this.options.available_filters[selected_filter], selected_filter));

                    /*
                    Reset the select, to show the first option
                     */
                    select_filters.val(0);
                }
            }

        }
    },
```

Comment: `$this` appears to be undefined within `.click()` handler. What is `.removeFilter()`?

Comment: What does `$this` refer to? How should we be able to help you without a [mcve]? There is nothing in the code you posted that gives any indication why the event handler might only be called once.

Comment: *"fired only once, removing one filter only."* What exactly does that mean? Do you expect **one** click to remove **multiple** filters? If so, which are the filters that you expect to be removed? What does `a.attr('filter')` return?
 How does `$this.removeFilter` work? Or is the event handler not called a second time if you click the element a second time? It's not clear what the issue is and you only provide incomplete information. Again, please provide a [mcve]. The more information you provide the easier it is for us to help you (or you figure out the problem on your own).

Comment: What do you mean by "only fires the click event once"? I don't see anything that triggers a click event, all I see is code that binds click handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).removeFilter(a.attr('filter'));
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `removeFilter` method by default. Also why do you think that this solves the OP problem?

Comment: dude its part of my code, and thats not the point.

Comment: its not gonna work. like i said, my code does work, but the click function gets fired only once

Comment: @M.Mar Show also `removeFilter` method implementation, maybe calling this method affects the element's handler or even the element itself (e.g. removing occurs).

Comment: its not the `removeFilter` method, because it doesnt get fired the second time. so it doesnt even call the `removeFilter` method

Comment: @M.Mar Since it got fired once, we need to investigate the effects of that triggering. Or maybe it's not true that it got fired once?